# Problems extending my Django user model

Tags: python, django

I have a simple django app, and am trying to set up a custom Django User Model so that I can have users log in with their email field.  I think I set everything up well enough, its all fairly straightforward, however when trying to actually run the migrations I get this error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial
```

Seems weird?

I'm having trouble understanding why it's having trouble understanding.

Heres the User model Im implementing

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(_('display name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

def get_full_name(self):
    '''
    Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
    '''
    full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    '''
    Returns the short name for the user.
    '''
    return self.first_name

def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    '''
    Sends an email to this User.
    '''
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

"Using a custom user model when starting a project"

If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises." reference->[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/)

Then you have to specify to setting.py that you are using a new user model (again before you migrate for the first time.)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

# in settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

---

I highly recommend checking out the link above.

Now to solve your problem you can delete your migrations in your app path under the migrations directory and reset your database and follow the instructions above.

**Changing user model mid project is difficult in django and requires manually editing your schema so since your project is for educational purposes just reset it**

Comment: by reset the database, do you mean drop the entire database?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have already created some User accounts or at least have created superuser account. Since you are changing the User model after I assume you have already made migrations at least once, Django has conflict with old user model with the new one.

Solution is to delete all accounts in admin including superuser. Then delete your migrations files in migrations folder. And also I think delete your sqlite data file. Run migrations again and it should work.

You should have created custom user model before any migration.

Comment: First django project, I'll remember this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to truncate the `django_migrations` table.

To do this you have to:

> login to your database (In case you use Mysql) using `mysql -u root -p`
>
> `use your_db_name;`
>
> `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` to prevent relation errors
>
> `DELETE FROM django_migrations;` truncates the `django_migrations` table
>
> `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Then you can run your migrations!

Another solution is to run these commands before your migration to avoid migrations error:

```
python manage.py migrate admin zero --fake
python manage.py migrate auth zero --fake
python manage.py migrate contenttypes zero --fake
python manage.py migrate sessions zero --fake
```

> ### Warning :
>
> This solution may leave you with a database schema that's
> inconsistent with the migrations applied, so only do this if
> you know what you're doing. Thanks to @AKX

You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48476148/14483074) solution too!

Comment: This solution may leave you with a database schema that's inconsistent with the migrations applied, so only do this if you know what you're doing.