# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, database-migration

When I run `python manage.py migrate` on my Django project, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 86, in handle
executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
File "/home/hari/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 298, in check_consistent_history
connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency account.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I have a user model like below:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first of all delete all the tables from the database, delete all the files from migrations folder except init.py then run migrate

Comment: how to delete all tables?

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: yah. i have deleted it and now it is working.

Comment: For me the problem was because I had a migration that depended on `'ipn', '__latest__'`. I just checked the order or migrations applied with `select * from django_migrations`, then changed `__latest__` by `'ipn', '0007_auto_20160219_1135'` and the problem has gone away.

Comment: @Exprator what database?

Comment: @Exprator Should I delete **db.sqlite3**?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your django_migrations table in your database is the cause of inconsistency and deleting all the migrations just from local path won't work.

You have to truncate the django_migrations table from your database and then try applying the migrations again. It should work but if it does not then run makemigrations again and then migrate.

Note: don't forget to take a backup of your data.

Comment: Didn't work. When I tried migrating it complained that a relation already exists.

Note that you can truncate django_migrations table with this command:

> python manage.py shell
```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE django_migrations")
```

And you can view the migration table like this:
```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all()
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea with a high likelihood of loss of data. See my answer below.

Comment: For fixing a local dev environment, this was the right solution for me - actually I just wiped out the whole DB, and it got recreated with all migrations ran fresh. My issue was I had run an old version of a `0001_initial` migration previously and the new one was not applying. If you want a clean migration history for prod without unneeded changes, deleting and regenerating migrations in local dev before ever shipping those migrations to prod seems fine to me. Other comments and answers point out deleting/clearing migrations won't work for a prod database, which is true.

Answer (score 242):

Since you are using a custom User model, you can do 4 steps:

1. Comment out django.contrib.admin in your INSTALLED_APPS settings

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>    ...
>    #'django.contrib.admin',
>    ...
> ]
> ```

2. Comment out admin path in urls.py

> ```
> urlpatterns = [
>    ...
>    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls) 
>    ...
> ]
> ```

3. Then run

> ```
>  python manage.py migrate
> ```

4. **When done, uncomment all back**

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem! I was changed default user model to Abstract User model , and after all migrations gave error. But when tried this , solved my problem!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The error msg is "No install app with label admin", do I need to delete all files in migrtations firstly? anyone know how to solve it ? Thanks  ~

Comment: Check below for user9414732 answer.

Comment: do not forget comment path('admin/', admin.site.urls) in urls.py

Comment: This has helped me so many times (I always forget this). I would never have guessed the custom user model to be the issue given the error.

Comment: Please make sure to stop server if you already have the "runserver" command currently active. then delete the migration folder for your apps. If you have nothing to loose then maybe flush the db or delete it altogether, then run the migration command again.

Comment: I also got the error msg "No install app with label admin" so i deleted the pycache folder in my migrations and it worked.

Comment: another quick way to do this is deleting the database if you're in development of course

Comment: this worked for me. i commented the django.contrib.admin in project's settings.py and also commend the admin path in project's urls.py, did python manage.py migrate then uncommented the previously commented codes.

Comment: I get **LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.**

Comment: It worked. but why did it happened? (i've initially migrated and created superuser then i tried to use custom user model)

Answer (score 129):

Lets start off by addressing the issue with most of the answers on this page:

**You never *have* to drop your database if you are using Django's migration system correctly and you *should* never delete migrations once they are comitted**

Now the best solution for you depends on a number of factors which include how experienced you are with Django, what level of understanding you have of the migration system, and how valuable the data in your database is.

In short there are two ways you can address any migration error.

1. Take the *nuclear* option. **Warning:** this is only an option if you are working alone. If other people depend on existing migrations you *cannot* just delete them.

   - Delete all of your migrations, and rebuild a fresh set with `python3 -m manage makemigrations`. This should remove any problems you had with dependencies or inconsistencies in your migrations.
   - Drop your entire database. This will remove any problems you had with inconsistencies you had between your actual database schema and the schema you should have based on your migration history, and will remove any problems you had with inconsistencies between your migration history and your previous migration files [this is what the `InconsistentMigrationHistory` is complaining about].
   - Recreate your database schema with `python3 -m manage migrate`
2. Determine the cause of the error and resolve it, because (speaking from experience) the cause is almost certainly something silly *you* did. (Generally as a result of not understanding how to use the migration system correctly). Based on the error's I've caused there are three categories.

   1. *Inconsistencies with migration files.* This is a pretty common one when multiple people are working on a project. Hopefully your changes do not conflict and `makemigrations --merge` can solve this one, otherwise someone is going to have to roll back their migrations to the branching point in order to resolve this.
   2. *Inconsistencies between your schema and your migration history.* To manage this someone will have either edited the database schema manually, or deleted migrations. If they deleted a migration, then revert their changes and yell at them; you should *never* delete migrations if others depend on them. If they edited the database schema manually, revert their changes and then yell at them; Django is managing the database schema, no one else.
   3. *Inconsistencies between your migration history and your migrations files.* [This is the `InconsistentMigrationHistory` issue the asker suffers from, and the one I suffered from when I arrived at this page]. To manage this someone has either manually messed with the `django_migrations` table or deleted a migration *after* it was applied. To resolve this you are going to have to work out how the inconsistency came about and manually resolve it. If your database schema is correct, and it is just your migration history that is wrong you can manually edit the `django_migrations` table to resolve this. If your database schema is wrong then you will also have to manually edit that to bring it in line with what it should be.

Based on your description of the problem and the answer you selected I'm going to assume you are working alone, are new to Django, and don't care about your data. So the nuclear option may be right for you.

If you are not in this situation and the above text looks like gibberish, then I suggest asking the [Django User's Mailing List](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/mailing-lists/#django-users) for help. There are very helpful people there who can help walk you through resolving the specific mess you are in.

Have faith, you can resolve this error without going nuclear!

Comment: For those interested: In my case, I had created a temporary migration to create tables in app B while I was waiting on my coworker to finish custom migrations to move the tables from app A to app B. When my coworker finished, I reverted my temporary migration and went to apply migrations. Bam error. Not only did I forget to unapply my temp migration, but had managed to name the temp migration the same as the actual one. To the migration system app B's `0001_initial` migration which depended on app A's `00XX_auto` migration had somehow been applied before it's dependency!

Comment: As horrible as all that sounds it was easy to solve. My database did have the correct schema so all I had to do was manually add `'A' '00XX_auto'` to the `django_migrations` table so my history reflected that the changes in that migration had been applied. Complicated, but not that hard once you work out the problem.

Comment: You can't just delete migrations, you need to delete the __pycache__ too

Comment: I got into this pickle because I had a bunch of non-Django tables of initial data so most of my models had `managed = False` in them.  When I decided to let to ORM do its job and move to managed models (as a way of getting my tests to run), then all my "fun" started.

Comment: You should _absolutely_ delete migrations if your team decides to squash 0001 through 0230 or however-many-hundred-migrations you have: you commit the squashed migration, you wait for CI/CD to apply it, and _once prod has fully caught up_ you delete the original 0001_... through 0230_... files because they do nothing anymore, and you back-update the squash migrations to no longer say it `replaces` anything. Keeping the old migrations around is only going to make dev life hell for your team when someone needs to figure out which of the umpteen 0002 migrations is the real one.

Comment: If your migrations are mixed up (dependency issues): use `python manage.py showmigrations` to see which migrations have been applied. Compare this with your django_migrations table in your database to see inconsistencies. Delete the entries from your django_migrations table that are out of order up to the dependency issue. Now, to fix the dependency, apply the migrations that are not yet reflected in the database to bring the database up to speed, and fake the ones that are already in the database to fix the migration history order. This only works if your migrations do not conflict. Tks @Airs

Comment: as the steps of squashing migrations explained in django documents,

Comment: Solution 2.3 worked for me, but I had to figure out the best way to modify django_migrations, which imho is not with a `truncate`.
My specific use case: I built an app using the native User model (auth_user table), and having 2 apps (admin + allauth) depending on it. 1y later I extend AbstractUser creating a CustomUser model still based on auth_user. `makemigrations` failed with `InconsistentMigrationHistory`.
Solution: `INSERT INTO django_migrations(app, name, applied) VALUES ('myapp', '0001_initial', <timestamp just preceding admin and account 0001_initial migrations timestamp>);`

Answer (score 74):

This happened to me in a new project after I added a custom User model, per the recommendation in the django docs.

[If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Here is what I did to solve the problem.

1. Delete the database db.sqlite3.
2. Delete the app/migrations folder.

Per @jackson, temporarily comment out django.contrib.admin.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
#‘django.contrib.admin’,
...
]
```

Also comment out the admin site in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', include('restapp.urls')),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

If you don't comment out the path('admin/'), you will get error "LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'" when you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

After the migrations finish, uncomment both of the above.

Comment: I never deleted the **db.sqlite3**. I only commented out `#‘django.contrib.admin’,` and `#path('admin/', admin.site.urls),`. Didn't need to delete  **db.sqlite3**, it worked anyways.

Answer (score 73):

Here how to solve this properly.

Follow these steps in your migrations folder inside the project:

1. Delete the _pycache_ and the 0001_initial files.
2. Delete the db.sqlite3 from the root directory (be careful all your data will go away).
3. on the terminal run:

     python manage.py makemigrations
     python manage.py migrate

Voila.

Comment: What if we don't want to delete and in production mode. Also I am not using `sqllite`, it's MySQL in our server. What's the better method without losing data.

Comment: Only answer here that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer 

Answer (score 41):

### Problem

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency account.0001_initial on database 'default'.

So we can migrate database without admin(admin.0001_initial) firstly.

After its dependency migrated, execute commands to migrate `admin.0001_initial`.

### Solution

1. remove 'django.contrib.admin' from INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.
2. execute commands:

> Python manage.py makemigrations appname
>
> Python manage.py migrate appname

3. add  'django.contrib.admin' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file.
4. execute commands again:

> Python manage.py makemigrations appname
>
> Python manage.py migrate appname

Comment: For me removing 'django.contrib.admin' from INSTALLED_APPS and running makemigrations results in `LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.`

Comment: go to urls.py and comment out urls with admin

Comment: Worked for me by following both suggestions.   Thank you!

Comment: the safest answer! Thanks @kunshi

Comment: that saves my ass, literally I thought it is not possible without wiping up the database but this trick worked!

Answer (score 11):

Before performing any other steps, back up your database. Then back it up again.

Remove any custom user model code out of the way, disable your custom model and app in settings, then:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth --natural-primary --natural-foreign > auth.json
python manage.py migrate auth zero  # This will also revert out the admin migrations
```

Then add in your custom model, set it in settings, and re-enable the app. Make sure you have no migrations on this app yet.

Then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your-app>
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata auth.json  # Assumes your user-model isn't TOO dissimilar to the standard one.
```

Done!

Answer (score 10):

Solved by commenting app **admin** before migration in settings.py

```
django.contrib.admin
```

and in urls.py,

```
('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

uncomment after migrate

Comment: post code (replacement) in script form and on top where code starts each block starts with a file name representing a script. How you posted your answer is confusing to me.

Comment: @ZF007 Sorry for the confusion. I am a little bit new to StackOverflow, so i did not understand how to post an answer

Answer (score 6):

Just **delete all** the `migrations` folders, `__pycache__`, `.pyc` files:

```
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$|migrations)" | xargs rm -rf
```

then, run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I have still issue can not fixed  can help on same

Comment: **Heads UP !**
This command will also remove Django's default migrations

Answer (score 5):

When you are doing some changes to default user model or you are making a custom user model by abstractuser then lot of times you will face that error

1: Remember when we create a superuser then for logging in we need username and password but if you converted USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' then now you can't login with username and password because your username field is converted into email....

[image: So Now it will show like this :]

and if you try to make another superuser then it will not ask for username it will only ask for email and password and then after creating superuser by email and password only when you try to login in admin pannel then it will throw that error because there is not any username and username field is required
[image: Error while creating superuser]

2: That's why after creating custom user model during migrate it will throw error so for
resolving it **first add AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.custommodelname' (appname is the app name where you definded your custom user model and custom model name is the name of the model which you gave to your custom user model) in your settings.py
3: Then delete the migrations folder of that app where you created that custom user model then delete the database db.sqlite3 of the project
4: Now run migrations python manage.py makemigrations appname(that app name where you defined your custom user model)
5: Then Migrate it by python manage.py migrate
6: That's it Now it is Done**

Comment: As of 06/2022, I had a similar situation where I transitioned to a custom user model mid project. I am using postgres instead of sqlite, so the instructions are slightly different. But the idea is you have to delete local "migrations" as well as all database tables. If you want to save some data on your production server, you'll have to do it manually. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) says basically the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete directly db.sqlite3， then migrate a new database is automatically generated. It should fix it.

```
rm sqlite3.db

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Only do if you dont mind deleting all your data!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was with pytest starting, where I just altered `--reuse-db` to `--create-db`, run pytest, and changed it back. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

### How to fix (Without delete migration folder or entire database)

1. Backup your database
2. Comment out your app in INSTALLED_APPS and AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User' in your settings.py
3. `python manage.py admin zero`
4. Undo step 2
5. `python manage.py migrate`

### Why this problem occured?

django admin app depends on `AUTH_USER_MODEL` which is default auth model when you create your django project.

If you migrate project models before change the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, django **admin** app apply migration as django **auth** model dependency. However, you change that **dependency** and want to migrate models again. So, the problem is occured here; admin models applied before its dependency, which is your **User** model now, applied. Thus, You should revert admin models migrations and then try it again.

Comment: `python manage.py admin zero` - what is that supposed to mean? Typo?

Answer (score 2):

just delete the sqlite file or run flush the databse 'python manage.py flush'
and then run makemigrations and migrate commands respectively.

Answer (score 2):

when you create a new Django project and run

> python manage.py migrate

The Django will create 10 tables for you by default including one auth_user table and two start with auth_user.

when you want to create a custom user model inherit from AbstractUser, you will encounter this problem with error message as follow:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency account.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I solve this problem by dropping my entire database, and create a new one. And this replaced the three tables I mentioned.

Comment: Okay, what if I wouldn't like to drop my database ? Is there any available solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Error is essentially:

```
Migration "B" is applied before its dependency "A" on database 'default'.
```

**Sanity Check**: First, open your database and look at the records in the 'django_migrations' table. Records should be listed in Chronological order (ex: A,B,C,D...).

Make sure that the name of the "A" Migration listed in the error matches the name of the "A" migration listed in the database. (They can differ if you had previously, manually, edited or deleted or renamed migration files)

**To Fix This**, rename migration A. either in the database or rename the filename. BUT make sure the changes matches up with what other developers on your team have in their databases (or the changes matches what on your production database)

Answer (score 2):

The order of `INSTALLED_APPS` seems important.
If you always put your recent works on top/beginning of the list they'll always be loaded properly in regard to django.contrib.admin. Moving my works to the beginning of the `INSTALLED_APPS` list fixed this problem for me.
The reason Kun Shi's solution may have worked maybe it ran the migrations in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

There is another reason besides user error that can lead to this sort of problem: [a known issue with Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29290) when it comes to squashed migrations.

We have a series of migrations that work perfectly fine in Python 2.7 + Django 1.11. Running `makemigrations` or `migrate` always works as it should, etc., even (for the purpose of testing) when the database is freshly re-created.

However, as we move a project to Python 3.6 (currently using the same Django 1.11) I've been stuck trying to figure out why the same migrations apply just fine only the first time they are run. After that, any attempt to run `makemigrations` or even just `migrate` results in the error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory
```

wherein migration `foo.0040-thing` is applied before its dependency `foo.0038-something-squashed-0039-somethingelse` (we only happen to have that one squashed migration... the rest are much more straightforward).

What's bugged me for a while is why this only happens on Python 3. If the DB is truly inconsistent this should be happening all the time. That the migrations appear to work perfectly fine the first time they are applied was equally confounding.

After much searching (including the present Q&A thread), I stumbled upon [the aforementioned Django bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29290). Our squash migration did indeed use the `b` prefix in the `replaces` line (e.g., `replaces = [(b'', 'foo.0038-defunct'),.......]`

Once I removed the `b` prefixes from the `replaces` line it all worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an empty database a quick fix could be running the migrations for the **account** app, before any other app migrations.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate account
```

And then:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to drop my database to and then run makemigrations and migrate again for this to be resolved on my part.

Answer (score 1):

These steps can as well work

1. Drop your entire database
2. Make a new migration

These few steps can solve it for you, and I think its best when you have multiple contributors to the sam project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a custom User model, you can first comment out

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
#'django.contrib.admin',
...
]
```

in your Installed_Apps settings. And also comment

```
urlpatterns = [
   # path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
   ....
   ....
]
```

in your base urls.py

Then run

```
python manage.py migrate.
```

When done uncomment

```
'django.contrib.admin'
```

and

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was also using a custom user. the following steps work for me.

1 - delete all migrations and database tables (If you have testing data !!!!).

2 - Run migrations for the custom user app.

```
python manage.py makemigrations customAuth
python manage.py migrate customAuth
```

3 - Then run migration for the project level.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete all the migrations and db.sqlite3 files and follow these steps:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations myapp 
$ ./manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0001(may be differ)
```

Delete the old migration file and finally.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If that exception was reveal itself while you are trying to create your own User model instead of standard follow that [instruction](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#no1)
I have found my problem resolve by follow that instruction step by step:

> 1. Create a custom user model identical to auth.User, call it User (so
>      many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set db_table='auth_user'
>      (so it uses the same table)
> 2. Throw away all your migrations
> 3. Recreate a fresh set of migrations
> 4. Sacrifice a chicken, perhaps two if you're anxious; also make a backup of your database
> 5. Truncate the django_migrations table
> 6. Fake-apply the new set of migrations
> 7. Unset db_table, make other changes to the custom model, generate migrations, apply them
>
> It is highly recommended to do this on a database that enforces
>   foreign key constraints. Don't try this on SQLite on your laptop and
>   expect it to work on Postgres on the servers!

Comment: Could you add a summary of or quote from the linked article to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you set **AUTH_USER_MODE**L in **settings.py** like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user_app_name.User'
```

you should comment this line before run **makemigration** and **migrate** commands. Then you can uncomment this line again.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in errors for me, e.g.: `accounts.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.`

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new project and with no apps, you run the

```
python manage.py migrate
```

the Django will create 10 tables by default.

If you want create a customer user model which inherit from `AbstractUser` after that, you will encounter this problem as follow message:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:
>   Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency
>   account.0001_initial on database 'default'.

finally,
I drop my entire databases and run

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when migrating from Wagtail 2.0 to 2.4, but have seen it a few other times when a third party app squashes a migration *after* your current version but before the version you’re migrating to.

The shockingly simple solution in this case at least is:

```
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

i.e. run a single migrate before trying to makemigrations.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem will come most of the time if you extend the User Model post initial migration. Because whenever you extend the Abstract user it will create basic fields which were present un the model like email, first_name, etc.

Even this is applicable to any abstract model in django.

So a very simple solution for this is either create a new database then apply migrations or delete ***[You all data will be deleted in this case.]*** the same database and reapply migrations.

Answer (score 0):

delete migrations folder and db.sqlite3 and type in the cmd
python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: While this may fix the problem, could you provide some information on why it will fix it as well?

Comment: cuz u already created an sql database with a structure and some data in it and when u make some changes that could touch ur data and modify ur model it runder an error

Answer (score 0):

**django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory #On Creating Custom User Model**

I had that same issue today, and none of the above solutions worked, then I thought to erase all the data from my local PostgreSQL database using this following command

```
-- Drop everything from the PostgreSQL database.

DO $$
DECLARE
        q TEXT;
        r RECORD;
BEGIN
        -- triggers
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pt.tgname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_trigger pt, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pt.tgrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pt.tgisinternal=false
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP TRIGGER %I ON %I.%I;',
                    r.tgname, r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- constraints #1: foreign key
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pcon.conname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint pcon, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pcon.conrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pcon.contype='f'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %I.%I DROP CONSTRAINT %I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname, r.conname);
        END LOOP;
        -- constraints #2: the rest
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname, pcon.conname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint pcon, pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace AND pc.oid=pcon.conrelid
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pcon.contype<>'f'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ONLY %I.%I DROP CONSTRAINT %I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname, r.conname);
        END LOOP;
        -- indicēs
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='i'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP INDEX %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- normal and materialised views
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind IN ('v', 'm')
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP VIEW %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- tables
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='r'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- sequences
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pc.relname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_class pc, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pc.relnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pc.relkind='S'
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP SEQUENCE %I.%I;',
                    r.nspname, r.relname);
        END LOOP;
        -- extensions (only if necessary; keep them normally)
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pe.extname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension pe, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pe.extnamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP EXTENSION %I;', r.extname);
        END LOOP;
        -- aggregate functions first (because they depend on other functions)
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname, pp.proname, pp.oid
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pp, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns, pg_catalog.pg_aggregate pagg
                WHERE pns.oid=pp.pronamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                    AND pagg.aggfnoid=pp.oid
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP AGGREGATE %I.%I(%s);',
                    r.nspname, r.proname,
                    pg_get_function_identity_arguments(r.oid));
        END LOOP;
        -- routines (functions, aggregate functions, procedures, window functions)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                WHERE attrelid='pg_catalog.pg_proc'::regclass
                    AND attname='prokind' -- PostgreSQL 11+
            ) THEN
                q := 'CASE pp.prokind
                        WHEN ''p'' THEN ''PROCEDURE''
                        WHEN ''a'' THEN ''AGGREGATE''
                        ELSE ''FUNCTION''
                    END';
        ELSIF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
                WHERE attrelid='pg_catalog.pg_proc'::regclass
                    AND attname='proisagg' -- PostgreSQL ≤10
            ) THEN
                q := 'CASE pp.proisagg
                        WHEN true THEN ''AGGREGATE''
                        ELSE ''FUNCTION''
                    END';
        ELSE
                q := '''FUNCTION''';
        END IF;
        FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT pns.nspname, pp.proname, pp.oid, ' || q || ' AS pt
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pp, pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns
                WHERE pns.oid=pp.pronamespace
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN (''information_schema'', ''pg_catalog'', ''pg_toast'')
            ' LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP %s %I.%I(%s);', r.pt,
                    r.nspname, r.proname,
                    pg_get_function_identity_arguments(r.oid));
        END LOOP;
        -- nōn-default schemata we own; assume to be run by a not-superuser
        FOR r IN (SELECT pns.nspname
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace pns, pg_catalog.pg_roles pr
                WHERE pr.oid=pns.nspowner
                    AND pns.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'public')
                    AND pr.rolname=current_user
            ) LOOP
                EXECUTE format('DROP SCHEMA %I;', r.nspname);
        END LOOP;
        -- voilà
        RAISE NOTICE 'Database cleared!';
END; $$;
```

After this you can run django command for migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And Absolutely that will work . Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve a weird InconsistentMigrationHistory issue in production

The logs looked like it worked fine:

```
>>> ./manage migrate
====== Migrations =====
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0024_xxx... OK
  Applying app.0025_yyy... OK
```

But then

```
>>> ./manage migrate
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration app.0025_yyy is applied before its dependency app.0024_xxx on database 'default'.
```

How to solve?
Change dependency of app.0025_yyy.py manually from `0024_xxx` to `0023_prior_migration_name`
Then:

```
>>> ./manage.py makemigrations --merge
Created new merge migration /app/src/app/migrations/0026_merge_20220809_1021.py
>>> ./manage.py migrate
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0024_xxx... OK
  Applying app.0026_merge_20220809_1021... OK
```

This solves the issue, but if you do not want to commit your changes you can just revert everything by doing:

```
>>> ./manage.py migrate app 0023
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying app.0026_merge_20220809_1021... OK
  Unapplying app.0024_xxx... OK
  Unapplying app.0025_yyy... OK
```

Revert dependency change of 0025_yyy and delete merge migration.

```
>>> ./manage migrate
====== Migrations =====
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0024_xxx... OK
  Applying app.0025_yyy... OK
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wrote this line:

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.CustomUser'

after INSTALLED_APPS, and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, and you are sure the issue is not because of inconsistent migration but because of auth model residing in a different db, then you can try suppressing the error message itself,

`lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 298, in check_consistent_history`

Here ,in the method check_consistenst_history, return before the migrations history is checked.

```
    def check_consistent_history(self, connection):
       """
       Raise InconsistentMigrationHistory if any applied migrations have
       unapplied dependencies.
       """
       return
    
       recorder = MigrationRecorder(connection)
       applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
       for migration in applied:
           # If the migration is unknown, skip it.
           if migration not in self.graph.nodes:
```

Ofcourse, please proceed with caution and this should be the last resort if nothing works.

Answer (score -1):

first of all backup your data. (copy your db file).

**delete sqlite.db and also the migration folder**.

then, run these commands:

```
./manage.py makemigrations APP_NAME
./manage.py migrate APP_NAME
```

after deleting the DB file and migration folder make sure that write the application name after the migration commands.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, before you do anything weird or nuclear, first just drop your database and rebuild it.

If using POsgres -

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC;
```

Then just remake your migrations

```
./manage.py migrate
```

This is the most basic solution, which typically will clear things up. Don't just go remaking the migrations until absolutely neccessary.

Comment: "anything weird or nuclear" and then "first just drop your database and rebuild it". If dropping the database isn't considered nuclear, I'd hate to see what is.

Comment: Your answer is the very nuclear b-o-m-b :))

Comment: `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration users.0001_initial is applied before its dependency auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length on database 'default'.` I have this and when I search for `0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length` in my codde I find it in two diffrent apps

Answer (score -1):

Comment django.contrib.admin from installed apps and also comment path('admin/', admin.site.urls),then rerun makemigrations and then migrate. It will solve your issue. For more info go [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

Comment: Some tips: try not to duplicate answers that already exist. There appears to be a selected solution already. If your answer is different, please elaborate on why, and provide more details if you can. For instance, what is the logic for comment on django.contrib.admin (also, do you mean comment out?). Why rerun the migration?