# Django Broken on MacOS

Tags: python, django, macos

I am working on a project on Django and I am facing an issue with it. I have done some migration wrong and decided to delete them from the project folder and rebuilt them. Since I did that Django is acting "*like deleted one of its source files*". The error occurs on every project I try to `migrate`, `makemigration`, `runserver`. I tried to reinstall django with pip but it does not help at all. I also delete the `.pyc` files but it did not help at all. I even generated new project but still ran on the same issue. I do think that is helpful but I have to mention that `shell` launches OK.

## The error

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1049a38c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 427, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 267, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 241, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0003_auto_20180326_1230 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('profile', '0003_auto_20180326_1230')
```

It is acting very weird and I still can't understand what might have caused the issue.

### Update

Using `virtualenv` I managed to get it working. I set up virtualenv with `python3` and I just ran `makemigrations`and it worked like nothing had ever happened. So I guess it is something wrong with the source files. On the other hand I still can't find what is causing the issue.

Comment: This is a inconsistent migrations problem. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651760/django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory/44651902#44651902. Also django's installation has nothing to do with this. The error is because of your mistake.

Comment: Yeah, it seems very logical to is my mistake but does Django fails on every project?

Comment: No it does not fail. Check out the link mentioned in my comment, read that question and answers carefully. If you still face problem then comment.

Comment: I tried every solution proposed in the question you mentioned but nothing worked. The same error coming up again and again... I even deleted the database. With no migration files and `makemigrations` fails

Answer (score 1):

The migration `admin.0003_auto_20180326_1230` depends on `profile.0003_auto_20180326_1230`.

As you deleted `profile.0003_auto_20180326_1230`, you should look at `admin.0003_auto_20180326_1230` to see if you can modify or remove it.

`admin.0003_auto_20180326_1230` should be in `admin/migrations/0003_auto_20180326_1230.py`

## Update

The use of virtualenv with Django is recommended. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip)

I personally use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) to manage my virtualenvs.

Django must have been mixing the migrations from differents projects as they weren't isolated by virtualenvs. Maybe it couldn't find the right settings module or something.

Comment: Actually, this is what I thought also, but the same issue occurs in totally irrelevant projects, plus I have no admin directory in my project. I cannot locate the file causing the issue anywhere on my computer.

Comment: Yea I know :|, I had set it up but forgot to activate it. This must be the issue. Any ideas on how to fix those conflicts? I think it may be the python cache files in the django directory.