# debug toolbar django not executing

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I've been trying to use the debug Toolbar from django by applying the [docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).
Before adding the  `INTERNAL_IPS=['127.0.0.1']` on `settings.py`, django can be executed locally and i can run it, but the toolbar doesn't appear.

Once I add the `INTERNAL_IPS=['127.0.0.1']`, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 97, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\middleware.py", line 133, in process_response
    panel.generate_stats(request, response)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\staticfiles.py", line 136, in generate_stats
    "staticfiles_finders": self.get_staticfiles_finders(),
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\staticfiles.py", line 148, in get_staticfiles_finders
    for path, finder_storage in finder.list([]):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 125, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\mydjan\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 313, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Alvaro Lloret\\Home\\alpha_trader\\static\\'
[10/Jan/2019 20:14:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 94293
```

Find hereby my settings.py:

```
import os

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'n2th-ublablalablablals'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin', # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44651902/5176549
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'debug_toolbar',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'crispy_forms',
    'accounts'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'alpha_trader.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'alpha_trader.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]



# Custom Django auth settings

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


# Messages built-in framework

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}

# Third party apps configuration

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

INTERNAL_IPS=['127.0.0.1']
```

Any idea why it is not working? It seems it is adding double slashes on my directory, but I don't know why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of your STATIC_ROOT setting?

Comment: I didn't modify it, so the default one. Should I change it?

Comment: What versions of python and django are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23), Django==2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the django docs for [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs), even on windows you need to pass the path in a Unix-style format:

> Note that these paths should use Unix-style forward slashes, even on
>   Windows (e.g. "C:/Users/user/mysite/extra_static_content").

**Solution**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static').replace("\\", "/"),
]
```