# raise InconsistentMigrationHistory( django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I run `python manage.py migrate`, and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 95, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\newspaper\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 302, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I have a custom user model, so here it is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I dont get any error in running `python manage.py makemigrations users`
What is the problem?

Comment: You can delete all the migration folders/files and then reset the database you are using & then make the migrations.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651760/django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651760/django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory)