# django error - InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency userauth.0001_initial

Tags: django, django-migrations

hello i get this error when i run the command below:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

what should I do?
I comment the `'django.contrib.admin',` but I get another error =) :

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

what should I do with this issue?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44651760

Comment: i didn't find an answer for my second error